# Visual Studio Error 175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid - but the provider is in the files

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

I joined a project on Visual Studio; I got the files through SVN, but when I try to build the code, I get a  Error 175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.
The error happens in my edmx file, between `<edmx:StorageModels>` and `</edmx:StorageModels>`, everything is underlined.

Here is the Provider causing a mess :

```
    <Schema Namespace="EntityModel.Store" Provider="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" ProviderManifestToken="11.2" Alias="Self" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
```

I checked the references in Visual Studio, and I do have 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess' in it. When I check the path in Reference, it does display a path where there is a Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll.

Also, I used WinMerge to compare my Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll with the one that is working on the computer of someone already in the project, and they are the same.

So do you have an idea why I have this error? 
Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT**

Hi everyone, 
So I solved that problem by executing the .bat in my C:\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_3\odp.net\managed\x86 file (xhere there were the Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.dll). 
I do have another issue now :

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'DataSetStorage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'll look at that, and let you know, in case someone stumbles upon the same problem :)

**LAST EDIT!**

So I deleted all the sources and copied them again from my friend's PC and it works now!

Comment: Did you configure the provider?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I am not sure how I can configure it. Should I add something in a .config?

Comment: Yes, running the ,bat is more or less executing the command I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess is not configured properly. Of course you could edit the .config file but you can make it automatically. Run this script, i.e. pick the lines you need:

```
SETLOCAL

set Oracle_x64=c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x64\odp.net
set Oracle_x86=c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x86\odp.net

set OraProvCfg_x64=%Oracle_x64%\bin\4\OraProvCfg.exe
set OraProvCfg_x86=%Oracle_x86%\bin\4\OraProvCfg.exe

set TNS_ADMIN=C:\oracle\network\admin


"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\managed\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.121.Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\managed\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.122.Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll

"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll /set:settings\TNS_ADMIN:%TNS_ADMIN%
"%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll /set:settings\TNS_ADMIN:%TNS_ADMIN%

rem Or without TNS_ADMIN configuration
rem "%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
rem "%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
```

Comment: Hi Wernfried, 
Thank you so much! In the meantime I had started to uninstall/reinstall Visual Studio, so I'll try your script if the error keeps appearing.

Comment: I always wonder why people make themselves so much work and uninstall/reinstall Visual Studio or reinstall even entire Windows when the solution is often just a few clicks (well - and sometimes some smart googling)

Comment: Yeah, I am quite a newbie so I was following advice I was given, (it's been a week now that I research my problem),  before seeing your script :) The error is unfortunately - and not surprisingly - still there, so I am now reading your script (thank you very much for that script).I have a few questions if you don't mind:
1) Is this a script I should execute it in the cmd? 
2) What does this script do exactly? If I understand well, it gives the path of my provider to my ODPM. What is an ODPM? I guess ODP stands for Oracle Data Provider, but what about the M? What does this script configure?

Comment: Also, what is the difference between the lines starting with ""%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac", and those starting with 'rem "%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:config'? Is it like first retrieving the files, and then linking them as providers? 
Also, I din't gave a PublisherPolicy folder in my managed folder, is it normal?

Comment: Run `OraProvCfg.exe` without any parameter, then you will get the help message. "ODPM" means "Oracle Data Provider Managed", there is also an unmanaged driver `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`. `/action:gac` adds (or `/action:ungac` for remove) the assembly to your [GAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache). It should be equivalent to [gacutil.exe /i](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/gacutil-exe-gac-tool), (resp. `gacutil.exe /u`). Action `/action:config` adds configuration to your `machine.config` file.

Comment: You can run the commands directly in cmd or put them into a `.bat` file. If you have version 12.1 (which is the first release) then you don't have any redirect policy, because at this time earlier versions did not exist.

Comment: Ok Wernfried, thank you so much! It did work, I am so happy!